# Example: Constant scalar curvature metric but not Einstein

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I understand that a Kaehler manifold $(M, \omega)$ (or any Riemannian manifold) has constant scalar curvature if it is Einstein.

The opposite is not true: it is possible to have a constant scalar curvature Kaehler metric which is not Einstein. I just can't think of any examples. Can you give me one? I think it would be useful for others too.

Comment: See this question from Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358280/examples-of-constant-scalar-curvature-k%c3%a4hler-metric-that-is-not-kahler-einstiein/358290#358290